# how to get the last updated record in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have audit table. On audit table one for trigger is fired for insert, updated, delete. 
I want to fire after update trigger on the same table to get other table's data.
For that I need the same updated record for data manipulation.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: the update trigger reacts to all rows updated as a dataset, asking for the last updated row doesn't make any sense.

Comment: thank u t-clausen.dk

Answer (score 0):

You can use inserted and deleted tables .

```
    if ((select count(*) from inserted)>0)
    //insert occurred
    begin
    do your stuff
    end

    if ((select count(*) from deleted )>0)
    //delete occurred
    begin
    do your stuff
    end

    if ((select count(*) from inserted)>0) and ((select count(*) from deleted)>0)
    //update occurred
    begin
    //do your stuff here
    end

or else you can use update() function or columns_update() function further

if(update('somecolumnname')=1 )
//above column is updated
//do your stuff

//to check multiple columns
more info here:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1479821/Using-ColumnsUpdated-in-a-Trigger.htm
```

Comment: Thank u.. I will try this